# How to move mongoDB database from from one server to another server using Ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I need to move mongoDB database from one server to another in Ubuntu. Suppose I have my database named as `Video` in this `10.*.*.*` and I need to move this DB to lets say `100.*.*.*`. I found the below command.

```
db.copyDatabase(fromdb, todb, fromhost, username, password, mechanism)
```

Is the above command will be able to do the task. Here I can not understand what should be the value assign to `mechanism`.

Answer (score 0):

That command should accomplish the task. The `mechanism` value is optional. The method `copyDatabase` defaults to `SCRAM-SHA-1` if the wire protocol version `maxWireVersion` is greater than or equal to 3 (i.e. MongoDB versions 3.0 or greater). You should only need to specify `mechanism` to be MONGODB-CR if you need to authenticate to the version 2.6.x `fromhost` from a version 3.0 instance or greater. Reference: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.copyDatabase/#definition

Comment: I have the version 2.4.9 and i did like this but it throws the error message as `could not connect to server 10.25.*.*:27017`.

Comment: @satya Could you provide the full command you used? I'm not clear on whether or not you specified a value for `mechanism` or omitted the value all together.

Comment: first i entered into my remote server mongodb. i typed this `db.copyDatabase('FGDP', 'FGDP', '10.25.*.*', 'root', '******')` command and it throe me the error `could not connect to server 10.25.*.*:27017` and from this instance i need to copy the whole database.

Answer (score 0):

I have just written this Project:
[mongo-server-migration](https://github.com/EtgarSH/mongo-server-migration)